# The difference between “even more surprise you” vs. “even surprise you more”

Tags: word-order

> What may **even** surprise you **more**...

vs.

> What may **even more** surprise you...

Do these two sentences have same meaning?

Is the first sentence right grammatically??

Answer (score 3):

The correct sentence would be "what may surprise you even more". The two sentences that you gave are not gramatically correct, or at least, they don't fall on the ear well -- the first sentence is more correct than the other, however.

The verb *may* leads to the adverb (how is it being verbed) being kicked to the end.